# How to control the unlocking screen in Android?

Tags: android

I want to create an APP that consists on answering an A/B/C/D question in order to unlock your screen (instead of the current unlocking screens that consist on setting your password.

I have looked for it an the only thing that I have found is Daylight mode, but according to what I have seen it doesn't respond to what I want.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Sample code here: https://github.com/Joisar/LockScreenApp

Only works on API Levels 8+, with some issues in ICS.

Comment: Yeah I have already found it but I find it a little dirty, is there any other library or "google" way.